# Can I improve on my existing validator that validates a property in a request is present when another (array) property contains a specific value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have this blade template for a create form I'm working on in my web app:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

use function Livewire\Volt\{rules, state};

state([
    'additionalDanceGenres' => [],
    'otherAdditionalDanceGenre' => '',
]);

rules(
    [
        'additionalDanceGenres' => 'array',
        //'otherAdditionalDanceGenre' => 'required_if:additionalDanceGenres.*,other|string',
    ]
);

$store = function () {
    $validated = $this->validate();

    $otherAdditionalDanceGenreValidator = Validator::make($this->all(), [
        'otherAdditionalDanceGenre' => Rule::requiredIf(in_array('other', $this->additionalDanceGenres)),
    ]);

    if ($otherAdditionalDanceGenreValidator->fails()) {
        $this->addError('otherAdditionalDanceGenre', 'The other additional dance genres are required.');
    }
    dd($this);
    // do something with the validated request
}

?>

<div>
    <form wire:submit="store">
        @php
        $danceGenres = array(
        array("id" => "ballet", "name" => "Ballet"),
        array("id" => "other", "name" => "Other")
        );
        @endphp

        <x-input-label for="additionalDanceGenre">Please select any additional dance genres</x-input-label>
        <x-input-group>
            @foreach ($danceGenres as $genre)
            <span>
                <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="additionalDanceGenres" name="additionalDanceGenre" value="{{  $genre['id'] }}" id="{{$genre['id']}}" />
                <x-input-label for="{{$genre['id']}}">{{ $genre['name'] }}</x-input-label>
            </span>
            @endforeach
        </x-input-group>

        @if(in_array('other', $additionalDanceGenres))
        <x-input-group>
            <x-input-label for="otherAdditionalDanceGenre">Your additional dance genres</x-input-label>
            <x-text-input wire:model="otherAdditionalDanceGenre" id="otherAdditionalDanceGenre" name="otherAdditionalDanceGenre" />
        </x-input-group>
        @endif


        @if ($errors->any())
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('additionalDanceGenres')" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('otherAdditionalDanceGenre')" />
        <hr class="my-2">
        @endif

        <x-primary-button>{{ __('Submit') }}</x-primary-button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This works well; I get the appropriate validation for `otherAdditionalDanceGenre` when `other` is in `additionalDanceGenres`. I tried to use a rule string (the commented-out value in `rules`; new to Laravel and unsure of the precise name for those) but what I have there didn't work.

I thought of passing the call to `Rule::requiredIf` in that `rules` array:

```php
rules(
    [
        'additionalDanceGenres' => 'array',
        'otherAdditionalDanceGenre' => Rule::requiredIf(in_array('other', $this->additionalDanceGenres)),
    ]
);
```

but that results in an  `Using $this when not in object context` error.

Is there a way to accomplish this validation without having to write a custom validator?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a rule and use it internally so you don't have to reinvent the bicycle

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class AvailableGenre implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return in_array('other', $this->request->get('additionalDanceGenres', []));
    }

  
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be valid');
    }
}
```

and then use it

```php
$otherAdditionalDanceGenreValidator = Validator::make($this->all(), [
    'otherAdditionalDanceGenre' =>  [new \App\Rules\AvailableGenre()],
]);
```